# WebSphere onMessage error : Exception data: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException

Tags: java, exception, websphere

Here's my problem :

We have a banking `Websphere` application `(version 7.0.0.27 )` on an `AIX` multi-instance server. On this application, we have received `51 MQ` **messages** in **1 min to process** but for 5 of them, we have the following errors :

```
[9/23/15 9:18:36:301 CEST] 00000065 LocalExceptio E   CNTR0020E: EJB threw an unexpected (non-declared) exception during invocation of method "onMessage" on bean "BeanId(TrefleIntermediationEAR#TrefleEJB-3.4.3.4.jar#OPFRestitutionReception, null)". Exception data: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor521.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:37)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:611)
    at com.ibm.ejs.jms.listener.ServerSessionDispatcher.dispatch(ServerSessionDispatcher.java:47)
    at com.ibm.ejs.container.MDBWrapper.onMessage(MDBWrapper.java:98)
    at com.ibm.ejs.container.MDBWrapper.onMessage(MDBWrapper.java:136)
    at com.ibm.ejs.jms.listener.ServerSession.run(ServerSession.java:574)
    at com.ibm.ws.util.ThreadPool$Worker.run(ThreadPool.java:1646)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: JMSCC0109: A message driven bean threw a runtime exception 'java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError'.
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:56)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:527)
    at com.ibm.msg.client.commonservices.j2se.NLSServices.createException(NLSServices.java:313)
    at com.ibm.msg.client.commonservices.nls.NLSServices.createException(NLSServices.java:388)
    at com.ibm.msg.client.jms.internal.JmsErrorUtils.createException(JmsErrorUtils.java:104)
    at com.ibm.msg.client.jms.internal.JmsSessionImpl.run(JmsSessionImpl.java:3018)
    at com.ibm.msg.client.jms.internal.JmsXAQueueSessionImpl$1.run(JmsXAQueueSessionImpl.java:395)
    at com.ibm.mq.jms.MQSession.run(MQSession.java:862)
    at com.ibm.ejs.jms.JMSSessionHandle.run(JMSSessionHandle.java:1055)
    at com.ibm.ejs.jms.listener.ServerSession.connectionConsumerOnMessage(ServerSession.java:1082)
    at com.ibm.ejs.jms.listener.ServerSession.onMessage(ServerSession.java:752)
    at com.ibm.ejs.jms.listener.ServerSession.dispatch(ServerSession.java:718)
    ... 8 more
Caused by: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at java.lang.J9VMInternals.initialize(J9VMInternals.java:222)
    at fr.bdf.trefle.trf.launcher.AbstractLauncher.retrieveOverridingStandaloneConnectionData(AbstractLauncher.java:117)
    at fr.bdf.trefle.trf.launcher.AbstractLauncher.createFactory(AbstractLauncher.java:83)
    at fr.bdf.trefle.trf.launcher.AbstractLauncher.<clinit>(AbstractLauncher.java:71)
    at java.lang.J9VMInternals.initializeImpl(Native Method)
    at java.lang.J9VMInternals.initialize(J9VMInternals.java:200)
    at fr.bdf.trefle.trf.dao.FlowMonitorServiceImpl.insertFlowMonitor(FlowMonitorServiceImpl.java:465)
    at fr.bdf.trefle.trf.dao.FlowMonitorServiceImpl.createFlowMonitor(FlowMonitorServiceImpl.java:176)
    at fr.bdf.trefle.trf.mdb.OPFRestitutionReception.onMessage(OPFRestitutionReception.java:213)
    at com.ibm.ejs.jms.listener.MDBWrapper$PriviledgedOnMessage.run(MDBWrapper.java:302)
    at com.ibm.ws.security.util.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:63)
    at com.ibm.ejs.jms.listener.MDBWrapper.callOnMessage(MDBWrapper.java:271)
    at com.ibm.ejs.jms.listener.MDBWrapper.onMessage(MDBWrapper.java:240)
    at com.ibm.mq.jms.MQSession$FacadeMessageListener.onMessage(MQSession.java:147)
    at com.ibm.msg.client.jms.internal.JmsSessionImpl.run(JmsSessionImpl.java:2846)
    ... 14 more
Caused by: java.util.MissingResourceException: Can't find resource for bundle configTechStandalone, key en_US
    at java.util.ResourceBundle.getBundleImpl(ResourceBundle.java:379)
    at java.util.ResourceBundle.getBundle(ResourceBundle.java:108)
    at fr.bdf.trefle.common.util.StandaloneTechConfigurable.<clinit>(StandaloneTechConfigurable.java:31)
    at java.lang.J9VMInternals.initializeImpl(Native Method)
    at java.lang.J9VMInternals.initialize(J9VMInternals.java:200)
    ... 28 more
```

From my analysis, here's what I can conclude :

- In the `stack trace`, the root error, mainly `java.util.MissingResourceException`, doesn't seem like the real cause because the `resource` the process is trying to get exists and for the other process, this works fine.
- I tried to see if the method used to get the `resource`, `getBundle()`, has some performance issue but I didn't find anything.
- I also tried to see if this was an already existing `IBM` bug but if it is the case, I can't find it.